# If() block changing the Meteor data received

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, reactjs

OK. I am speechless. I encountered this weird behavior like two days ago and I can't really tell what is going on.

In my code I have:

```
character: Characters.find({
    'user._id': Meteor.userId(),
    'gameId': this.props.gameId
}).fetch(),
```

It is inside the getMeteorData function (I use Meteor with React), mixin [ReactMeteorData] is also present.

Now in the `componentWillMount()` function I have this piece of code. What I want to do is to check if there is a character inside created by this user and in this game.

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    console.log(this.data.character);
}
```

It returns `[Class]` with the character I was looking for. Great! So now I add this piece of code and it looks like this:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    console.log(this.data.character);

    if (this.data.character.length > 0) {
        console.log('yay!');
    } else {
        console.log('nay...');
    }
}
```

So that's a normal, unsuspicious `if()`. Guess what I get from that first `console.log()`: `[]`. WHY? Why is it that this `if` is changing what I get from my DB?!

Comment: I don't see a conditional block changing any value. I see an empty array. are you sure that `this.data.character` is loaded and corectly assigned? do you actually have database entries?

Comment: Yes. As I said, without that `if()` block I get a `[Class]` and within it there is the object I want. I'm starting to suspect it might have something to do with subscriptions and the time it takes for them to load.

Comment: Ah sorry. Did not get that. Yes, race conditions may be an issue here (especcially with meteor/node non-blocking database io). Can you assign any callbacks to `Characters.find(..)` or `(..).fetch()` to process your data?

Comment: Meteor is "technically" synchronous. I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Ok. I'm not familliar with meteor.

Comment: Are you sure, that your subscription is ready, when `componentDidMount` is being called?

Comment: I added an answer. It would seem that adding and `if()` block was enough to change the outcome of the race between code and subscription. The way to subscribe I described in my answer is free of such problems. At least for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that subscriptions were not ready when I tried to use them. What I did is rewrite the way subscriptions are made. I moved it from the router (so no subscriptions there) to the component itself. Like this:

```
data = {}
subs = {}

subs.something = Meteor.subscribe("something", argument);

if (subs.something.ready()) {
    data.something = Somethings.find({}).fetch();
    // the same query I use in publish method but with .fetch()
    // because otherwise Meteor throws a warning
}
```

This is the code that goes to the `getMeteorData` function. And then inside the `render()` I can use those subscriptions like this:

```
render: function() {
    return(
        <p>{this.data.something ? this.data.something.property : 'Loading...'}</p>
    );
}
```

And then it works perfectly fine. I had rewritten all of my components to use this way of doing things and now I have NO problems with subscriptions whatsoever. It also feels more "componentish" and "reactish" as everything including subscriptions is included in the parent component and the relevant data is being passed to children via props. No need to look for code and subscription methods in the router.